# Computing explicitly three integrals involving radial functions

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus

How can I compute the following three (similar)
integrals?
$$
\int_{\mathbb R^N} \left(\frac{1}{1+|x|^2} \right)^{\beta} dx
$$
$$
\int_{\mathbb R^N} \left(\frac{1}{1+|x|^2} \right)^{(N+2\alpha)/2} \left(\frac{1}{|x|} -\frac{1}{(1+|x|^2)^{1/2}} \right) dx
$$
$$
\int_{\mathbb R^N} \left(\frac{1}{1+|x|^2} \right)^{(N+2\alpha)/2} |x|^{4\alpha - N} dx
$$
where $\alpha, \beta >0$. Since the involved functions are radial, one can make a change of variables to reduce the problems to 1-d problems, but then I don't know how the integral can be computed explicitly or it if can be done in an easy way at all or not.

Comment: Do you need to compute them explicitly? It is unlikely to have a nicer closed form than a possible beta function without integer or half integer $\alpha,\beta$, and there are conditions on the convergence more stringent than $\alpha,\beta > 0$

Comment: @NinadMunshi I'd also accept something involving the Euler Gamma function as an "explicit" form. What stronger conditions than $\alpha, \beta >0$ do you need for the convergence?

Comment: The first integral requires $\beta>\frac{N}{2}$, the second $\alpha > -\frac{3}{2}$ provided $N>1$, and the third $\alpha < \frac{N}{2}$

Comment: @NinadMunshi Ok, we can assume these.

Comment: @NinadMunshi Could you add some details in an answer about why these imply convergence and, if possible, an explicit computation of the solution, please?

Comment: I'd like to, but I posted these in a comment because I do not know how to compute the integrals and feel an answer discussing their convergence would not be an answer to the question. To derive them, just use the fact that the spherical coordinates Jacobian has a radial factor of $|x|^{N-1}$ and your usual asymptotics for large and small $|x|$ in $1$D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All these integral can be expressed through Beta function. Let's take, for instance, the first one: $I(n,\beta)=\int_{\mathbb R^N} \left(\frac{1}{1+|x|^2} \right)^{\beta} dx_1..dx_n=\int_{\mathbb \Omega}d{\Omega}\int^\infty_0\left(\frac{1}{1+r^2} \right)^{\beta} r^{n-1}dr$, where we integrate over all angles ($d{\Omega}$) in a polar system of coordinate.

Because the integrand is a scalar (and does not depend on angles), integration over $d{\Omega}$ can be done straightforward. We can use, for instance, the following trick:
$\int_{\mathbb x_1}..\int_{\mathbb x_n}e^\left(-x_1^2-..-x_n^2\right)d{x_1}..d{x_n}=(\int_{\mathbb x}e^{-x^2}dx)^n=\left(\sqrt{\pi}\right)^n=\int_{\mathbb \Omega}d{\Omega}\int^\infty_0e^{-r^2} r^{n-1}dr=\frac{1}{2}\int_{\mathbb \Omega}d{\Omega}\int^\infty_0e^{-t} t^{\frac{n}{2}-1}dt  (t=r^2)=\frac{1}{2}\Gamma(\frac{n}{2})\int_{\mathbb \Omega}d{\Omega} \Rightarrow $$\int_{\mathbb \Omega}d{\Omega}=\frac{2(\sqrt{\pi})^n}{\Gamma(\frac{n}{2})}$ (where ${\Gamma}(x)$ is Gamma function).

$I(n,\beta)=\frac{2(\sqrt{\pi})^n}{\Gamma(\frac{n}{2})}\int^\infty_0\left(\frac{1}{1+r^2}\right)^{\beta} r^{n-1}dr= \frac{(\sqrt{\pi})^n}{\Gamma(\frac{n}{2})}\int^1_0(\frac{1-t}{t})^{\frac{n}{2}-1}t^{\beta-2} dt (t=\frac{1}{1+r^2})=\frac{(\sqrt{\pi})^n}{\Gamma(\frac{n}{2})}B(\frac{n}{2};\beta-\frac{n}{2})=(\sqrt{\pi})^n\frac{\Gamma(\beta-\frac{n}{2})}{\Gamma(\beta)}$

The formula gives itself the the answer when it is valid: ${\beta}>\frac{n}{2}$.
The second and third integral can be evaluated in the same fashion - just make designated substitutions and use formula for Beta function (and its relation with Gamma function) https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function.

PS  Third integral $=\frac{(\sqrt{\pi})^n}{\Gamma(\frac{n}{2})}B(2{\alpha};\frac{n}{2}-{\alpha})=(\sqrt{\pi})^n\frac{\Gamma(2\alpha)\Gamma(\frac{n}{2}-\alpha)}{\Gamma(\frac{n}{2})\Gamma(\frac{n}{2}+\alpha)}$ - valid for $0<\alpha<\frac{n}{2}$

Second integral $=\frac{(\sqrt{\pi})^n}{\Gamma(\frac{n}{2})}\left(B({\alpha}+\frac{1}{2};\frac{n}{2}-\frac{1}{2})-B({\alpha}+\frac{1}{2};\frac{n}{2})\right)=(\sqrt{\pi})^n\frac{\Gamma(\frac{1}{2}+\alpha)}{\Gamma(\frac{n}{2})}\left(\frac{\Gamma(\frac{n}{2}-\frac{1}{2})}{\Gamma(\frac{n}{2}+\alpha)}-\frac{\Gamma(\frac{n}{2})}{\Gamma(\frac{n}{2}+\alpha+\frac{1}{2})}\right)$. In this case, we have uncertainty at $\alpha =-\frac{1}{2}$, so it is easier to get from the original integral at $x\rightarrow \infty$ that integral is valid for $\alpha>-\frac{3}{2}$ and $n>1$.

Comment: Thank you very much! Could you please add also the solution to the second and third integral? Here the additional terms make the application of the technique in your answer more difficult and different.

Comment: I added calculations of second and third integrals. Good luck.

Comment: Thank you very much!